# Making htaccess deflect all spambot referrers

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to block spambots using .htaccess

Currently this is what I have been trying but they still seem to be getting through and I can't understand why - maybe because the referrer is like http://wwww.othits.net/account rather than http://www.othits.net?

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} semalt.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} buttons-for-website.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} otohits.net [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} 10khits.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} exc.10khits.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} seoanalyses.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{HTTP_REFERER} [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the actual full protocol and subdomains if present. i.e. www. 
Try this rule below. It's one condition and it accounts for http/https and www if present.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(www\.)?(semalt\.com|buttons-for-website\.com|otohits\.net|10khits\.com|exc\.10khits\.com|seoanalyses\.com)(/.*)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* - [F]
```

Comment: What about the URI as well? semalt.com/account/autosurf or whatever?

Comment: The regex just looks for it starting with the protocol and domain but it should account for uri as well. You shouldn't need to specify it. Give it a shot and see if it's working.

Comment: Ok modified the rule. See if that helps.

Comment: Still getting through sadly the full url is http://www.otohits.net/account/autosurf

Comment: Ah wait maybe it's cached on the edge cache....going to invalidate the caches....sorry

Comment: do you have any other conditions with that? That should be working.

Comment: Going to try to invalidate the CDN - I think maybe it's serving a cached version of the page